# how to allow duplication of data while updating the existing data in mongoDB using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mongodb

I have a problem while updating the database. when I want to update an existing data in db i was not able to update the data if any one of the value is same as original value present in database. For example if "abc" is student name and "123" is marks, if i only want to change marks to "100" and keep the name "abc" if I press update it says "error duplicate entry".
This is the code for update function using ajax found in index.php.

```
function update(){
        var _id = $('#edit_id').val();
        var studentname = $('#editStudentname').val();
        var marks = $('#editMarks').val();  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {_id:_id,studentname:studentname,marks:marks},
            success: function(data){
                $('#editModal').modal('hide');
                $('#studentname,#marks').val('');
                if(data ==0){
                    alertify.error('Error! Duplicate Entry');
                }
                else{
                    alertify.success('Updated Successfully');                       
                    $edit_row.addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $edit_row.closest("tr").find(".studentname").text(studentname);
                    $edit_row.closest("tr").find(".marks").text(marks);
                    removeActive($edit_row);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the php code for update in update.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$query = array('studentname' => new MongoRegex('/^'.preg_quote($_POST['studentname']).'$/i'));  
$cursor = $collection->find($query)->count();

if($cursor == 0){
    $id = new MongoId($_POST['_id']);
    $document = $collection->findone(array('_id' => $id));

    //update
    if((isset($_POST['studentname']) && $_POST['studentname'] != null)&&(isset($_POST['marks']) && $_POST['marks'] != null)){
        $collection->update(
            array( '_id' => new MongoId($_POST['_id'])),
            array( '$set' => array( 'studentname' => $_POST['studentname'], 'marks' => $_POST['marks'] ) )
        );
    }
    echo 1;
}
else{
    echo 0;
}?>
```

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Looks like your php code is only checking on the name property, so since you are changing marks but not the name, it returns that it is a duplicate. You need to change the php code to check for a record that matches both the studentname and the marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible solution.
by changing the following line

```
 $query = array('studentname' => new MongoRegex('/^'.preg_quote($_POST['studentname']).'$/i'));
```

to the below one

```
$query = array('studentname'); /*=> new MongoRegex('/^'.preg_quote($_POST['studentname']).'$/i'));*/
```

the following function actually used to find regual expression pattern.
As found in this http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

```
MongoRegex('/^'.preg_quote($_POST['studentname']).'$/i'));
```